# Get users with UID >= 1000 from /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, shell-script, passwd, uid

I am trying to get usernames from `/etc/passwd` if UID equal/greater than 1000 using a `for` loop. The below simple `bash` script works but prints the username twice for some reason.

```
#!/bin/bash

for userid in `awk -F: '{print $3}' /etc/passwd`
do
if (("$userid" >= 1000)); then
echo "Valid User" :`cat /etc/passwd | grep $userid | awk -F: '{print $1,$3}'`
fi
done
```

Comment: Why not just `awk -F : '$3 >= "1000" {print "Valid User " $1,$3}' /etc/passwd` ?

Comment: Correction of double quotes around 1000: `awk -F : '$3 >= 1000 {print "Valid User " $1,$3}' /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this,

```
 awk -F ':' '$3>=1000 {print "Valid User :"$1","$3}'  /etc/passwd
```

maybe you might have the user IDs like 1000 and 10001. So your grep leads to duplicate while iterating in for loop.

Try as

```
 echo "Valid User" :`cat /etc/passwd | grep ":$userid:" | awk -F: '{print $1,$3}'`
```

Comment: Thanks @msp9011

awk -F ':' '$3>=1000 {print "Valid User :"$1","$3}'  /etc/passwd

Comment: Can you tell me why the "for" loop prints username twice? Just to understand the loops.

Thank you,

Comment: @Kumar as mentioned in the answer , the duplicate happens becos grep is not having boundaries.... if we use `grep XX` it will get you both XX and XXX. So you should have boundaries to iterate properly like `grep "\bXX\b"` or with a static string which I used in the answer as `grep ":$userid:"`

Comment: @msp9011 His comment gives the correct output as yours has a syntax error. By having `3` and not `$3` before muru edited it, your answer prints the username and then a comma and the number 3 when he wants it to print the username and the userid.

Comment: You don't need cat.