# Loop over users problem

Tags: linux, shell, slackware, uid

I am struggling with a loop over users id, i want to list all the users in /etc/passwd whose id are greater than 999, it doesn't recognize my if .. fi sentence and it is important to say that I am working with the minimal installation so I don't have commands as 'awk', this is my actual code

```
cat /etc/passwd | while IFS=: read name pass uid gid geos home; do if [$uid > 999]; then echo $name di done;
```

I have also tried with -gt but it does't work either

Comment: Consider installing `awk`. It's a few hundred KB.  Then see [Get users with UID >= 1000 from /etc/passwd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/533663)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces around the brackets:

this:

```
if [$uid > 999];
```

should be:

```
if [ "$uid" -gt 999 ];
```

And if you compare numbers use `-gt`. And do not forget to quote the variables

Also the end of `if` structure is `fi`, not `di`

The script should be:

```
cat /etc/passwd | while IFS=: read name password uid gid geos home; do if [ "$uid" -gt 999 ]; then echo $name ;fi ;done
```

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you don't have `awk`. That's a pity because it would have been a highly efficient solution:

```
awk -F: '$3 > 999' /etc/passwd
```

If you have `grep` and `cut` you can extract your users by virtue of the uid having at least four characters:

```
grep '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:][^:][^:][^:]' /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

Or `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/^\([^:]*\):[^:]*:[^:][^:][^:][^:].*/\1/p' /etc/passwd
```

If you find you really do need to loop around using a shell, here's a version of your fixed code. Principally the mistake was forgetting that `[` is a command and therefore needs whitespace around for the tokeniser. I've also tidied up the `read`.

```
while IFS=: read -r name x uid gid geos home shell
do
    [ "$uid" -gt 999 ] && echo "$name"
done
```

Putting your code through https://shellcheck.net/ would have helped you. I'd recommend it for next time.